# Disable ability to download images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to disable save/copy options on all the images on my application except for the images which are inside an anchor tag ( tag).

Comment: It's not possible to prevent this without a high-tech algorithm and different framework. Because image and all others files are stored in a separate folder and can be viewed by their URL.

Comment: For that, an image is divided into very small parts and saved with a random string name. so that if it will become very difficult for the others to get the full picture by combining those parts of the images.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think It is possible to stop user from saving images from browser. All application is present on browser in form of html. Any user can easily inspect and save you image. You may restrict right click on application. But still there are many way to open debugger.

> Best you can post a disclaimer that images are copyrighted!

All the best

Comment: You cannot write a disclaimer without having a real copyright to it.

Comment: @RajatJain Yes, No point of doing so much if image are not actually yours.

Comment: But it's not possible everytime to take copyright of everything as it costs you. And the question was about how to prevent it from being saving. Even if one is copyrighted other can save it.

Comment: Yes you are right. But still for an amount it stops user mentally from copying.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to prevent this without a high-tech algorithm and different framework. Because image and all others files are stored in a separate folder and can be viewed by their URL.

A webpage is open in read mode. So, the user also has access to read images separately.